# Copy activitiy (from Cosmos SQL api to ADLS gen2) getting failed in Synapse

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to run a pipeline which copies data from Cosmos (SQL API) to ADLS gen2 for multiple tables. Lookup Activity is passing list of queries and Copy Activity runs within ForEach, using self-hosted IR.
However it keeps failing after 1st iteration with below error:

> Operation on target Copy data1_copy1 failed: Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Upload file failed at path tfs/OU Cosmos Data/LATAM/fact\dl-br-prod.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestTimeoutException,Message=Request timed out.

Also I'm sure it is not the issue with any one specific table since I have tried passing queries in different order, in each attempt first query passed completes successfully and for rest of iteration Copy Activity runs for sometime and eventually fails.

I have tried following so far:

1. Running ForEach in sequential mode
2. Changing **Block Size (in MB)** on Sink side to 20MB. By default it is 100MB

Comment: did you fins a way around this ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT So far best alternative suggested from Microsoft Support is to use Synapse Link instead. But it has it's own limitations, given that we need to use Self-hosted IR.

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT refer to my latest answer for conclusive findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get response from Microsoft Cosmos product team:

> Root cause:
>
> The SDK client is configured with some Timeout value and the request
> is taking longer time.
>
> Reason for the timeouts is an increase in Gateway latency (Gateway has
> no latency SLA) due to large result size. This is probably expected
> (more data tends longer to be read, sent, and received).
>
> Resolution:
>
> Increase the RequestTimeout used in the client.
>
> The team owning the Synapse Data Transfer (which uses the .NET 2.5.1
> SDK and owns the Microsoft.DataTransfer aplication) can increase the
> RequestTimeout used on the .NET SDK to a higher value. In newer SDK
> versions, this value is 65 seconds by default.

Though we have opted to bypass this route altogether and include either SynapseLink or Private Endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the workaround suggested in the official MS docs as this involves Self-Hosted IR.

[Request to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account caused a timeout error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-azure-data-lake#request-to-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-caused-a-timeout-error)

**Cause:** The issue is caused by the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 sink timeout error, which usually occurs on the Self-hosted Integration Runtime (IR) machine.

**Recommendation:**

> 1. Place your Self-hosted IR machine and target Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account in the same region, if possible. This can help
>    avoid a random timeout error and produce better performance.
> 2. Check whether there's a special network setting, such as ExpressRoute, and ensure that the network has enough bandwidth. We
>    suggest that you lower the Self-hosted IR concurrent jobs setting when
>    the overall bandwidth is low. Doing so can help avoid network resource
>    competition across multiple concurrent jobs.
> 3. If the file size is moderate or small, use a smaller block size for nonbinary copy to mitigate such a timeout error. For more information,
>    see [Blob Storage Put
>    Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block)

Comment: Actually I tried to follow recommendations: self-hosted IR and storage account both are configured for same Location. Data size is in ~tens GBs so have left **Write Batch Size** to default that is 100 MB. As for n/w bandwidth, there are separate pipelines which successfully writes data in ~TBs. Is there anything specific I'm missing?